# How to create an autosys job that would run between 5th to 7th business days of every month?

Tags: autosys

Not getting date selection options in autosys. Kindly provide some inputs.

I have checked the date_condition option but it just contains days of week like mo, tu but not any option to select dates. I want to run my job between 5th to 7th business days each month.